# What is the Laurent Series of $\cos{\frac{1}{\sqrt{z}}}$ at point $z=0$?

Tags: complex-analysis

The function $\cos{\frac{1}{\sqrt{z}}}$ is analytic at any neighborhood of $z=0$, but I find it hard to get the Laurent Series of the function. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\cos z = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n z^{2n}}{(2n)!}
\\
\cos \frac{1}{\sqrt{z}} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n z^{-n}}{(2n)!}
\end{align}$$
what's wrong with that?